# What does "I'm there" mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

PJ met a girl Emma at the park. By accident, PJ brought home the baby who had been with Emma, and Emma took back to her home the baby who had been with PJ. PJ tried to call Emma, but found Emma gave him a fake number.

The sister Teddy said, "Come on, let's go to the park."

The younger brother Gabe said,

> to meet the girl who blew off PJ. *I'm there*.

What does "I'm there" mean?

Comment: Was this conversation through phone or text? Or just normal speech?

Comment: It's normal speech.

Comment: Maybe Gabe is eager to see the girl (“I want to be there”, “I am already there”) , or he does not want to meet her and says it sarcastically

Comment: More context may be useful to properly answer the question. I agree with @AndrewTobilko's suggestion of "I want to be there", or it might be a shorthand for "I am going to go there with you" which itself can be shortened to "I am going there" or "I am going with you".

Comment: I'd like to, but the TV show Good Luck Charlie doesn't give any more context.

Comment: Off-topic, but... The French language equivalent of the phrase "I'm here" is "je suis là", the literal translation of which is "I'm there".  I always found it amusing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is probably slang meaning "I accept your invitation; I enthusiastically agree; I am in agreement with this plan."

References:

- [Urban Dictionary: I'm there](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=I%27m+there)
- [The Free Dictionary: I'm there!](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/I%27m+there!)

Comment: "I'm in" is a similar piece of slang. Perhaps a little more commonly used.